# Android' fts3 table doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

1.

```
int mWordId = 65535;
String[] projection = {
    "wordId",
    "rank",
        };
String selection = "wordId MATCH ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = {Integer.toString(mWordId)};

Cursor c = pDatabase.query("words"
    ,projection
    ,selection
    ,selectionArgs
    ,null
    ,null
    ,"rank DESC");

c.moveToFirst();
int count= c.getCount();
```

2.

```
int mWordId = 65535;
String[] projection = {
    "wordId",
    "rank",
        };
String selection = "wordId =? ";
String[] selectionArgs = {Integer.toString(mWordId)};

Cursor c = pDatabase.query("words"
    ,projection
    ,selection
    ,selectionArgs
    ,null
    ,null
    ,"rank DESC");

c.moveToFirst();
int count= c.getCount();
```

3.

```
String query = "SELECT wordId,rank From words WHERE wordId=65535 ORDER BY rank DESC";
Cursor c = pDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
c.moveToFirst();
int count= c.getCount();
```

In 1, I use "match" and the number of result is 1.
In 2, I use "=" and the number of result is 0.
In 3, I use "=" and rawQuery(). The number of result is 1.

I cant find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1, `MATCH` works only with strings, so it converts all values of the `wordId` column to strings and searches them for the string `'65535'`.

In 2, you are comparing the values in the `wordId` column with the string `'65536'`.

In 3, you are comparing the values in the `wordId` column with the number `65536`.

You should use parameters (`selectionArgs`) only for strings, not for numbers.

Please note that the only queries that work efficiently on FTS tables are lookups with `MATCH` and lookups on the `rowid`/`docid`.
If you need other lookups, you database schema is not designed correctly.